# Diferenciar 2 usuarios dentro de otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Tengo una dilema, tengo dos tablas iniciales; **usuario y carro**. la tabla carro tiene una columna llamada `cash_car` que contiene un total de dinero en numero entero. Necesito diferenciar el total que ha ingresado cada usuario (en este caso solo dos).¿ Alguna idea para mejorar el modelo de datos ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías elaborar más la pregunta? A que te refieres con diferenciar el total que se ha ingresado?

Comment: Tengo dos usuarios que ingresan datos a la tabla carro, por ejemplo un total de dinero, y estos dos usuarios desean consultar lo que han ingresado cada uno, no el total de los dos. me entiendes? @Yikarus

Comment: En teoría se debe de insertar un registro en la tabla carro por usuario, asociado con un id de usuario, para que a la hora de consultar el dinero de cada usuario solo se obtenga lo que cada uno ingresó

Comment: si asi es, pero con id como podre diferenciarlos entre los dos por nombre, a menos que mi primary key sea el nombre @Yikarus

Comment: Tienes que hacer `JOIN` de ambas tablas usando la columna que las relaciona, en este caso `id_user`. Ejemplo: `SELECT * FROM usuario u INNER JOIN carro c ON u.id_user=c.id_user WHERE u.id_user=1`. Esa consulta te traerá todas las columnas de ambas tablas del usuario 1. Puedes cambiar el `*` por los nombres de columnas que quieras. He usado `u` y `c` como alias de cada tabla.

Comment: @A. Cedano pero si deseo solo traer una columna de la tabla carro de un usuario de nombre determinado ?

Comment: Haces: `SELECT c.nombre-columna ... WHERE u.name_user='Nombre-Usuario'`... y el resto de la consulta como explicado antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solución 1

**Si hay una relación 1:1 o sea, un usuario por un carro**

Puedes dejar las tablas como están.

Para la consulta, tendrías que hacer `JOIN` de ambas tablas usando la columna que las relaciona, en este caso `id_user`.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario u 
INNER JOIN 
carro c ON u.id_user=c.id_user 
WHERE u.id_user=1;
```

Esa consulta te traerá todas las columnas de ambas tablas del usuario 1. Puedes cambiar el `*` por los nombres de columnas que quieras. He usado `u` y `c` como alias de cada tabla.

---

### Solución 2

**Si hay una relación 1:M o M:M**

O sea, si un carro lo podrían usar varias personas, o si la misma persona podría usar el mismo carro en fechas diferentes...

Necesitarás una tercera tabla que gestione las relaciones. ¿Por qué? Porque de ese modo, cada vez que alguien vaya a usar un carro no tienes que repetir todas las columnas del carro una y otra vez. Así se evita la redundancia de datos y muchos otros factores.

Algo que ayuda en el caso de tablas como `usuario`, `carro`... es pensar cada fila de nuestra tabla como una entidad única, que nunca debería repetirse.

Esa tercera tabla llamada sintomáticamente `usuario_carro` sería más o menos así:

- `id` (PK autoincremental)
- `id_user`
- `id_carro`
- `fecha`

Tendría un índice único combinando `id_user` y `id_carro` para evitar que un mismo usuario pueda tener dos veces el mismo carro. O bien el índice único combinaría las columnas (`id_user, id_carro, fecha`) para evitar que el mismo usuario pudiese tener más de una vez el mismo carro en la misma fecha... Eso dependerá del contexto de tu aplicación.

La consulta entonces sería así:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario_carro uc 
INNER JOIN 
usuario u ON uc.id_user=u.id_user 
INNER JOIN carro c ON uc.id_carro=c.id_carro 
WHERE u.id_user=1;
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, solo tengo dos usuarios que ingresaran datos a la tabla carro, estos dos usuarios son admins. Probare y comentare que tal ...